# Rails SocketError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailman

I am trying to access mail of **outlook** using **mailman** But I am getting an error. 
**getaddrinfo: Name or service not known**
I was able to do of gmail with the code but when i tried for outlook it is giving me  error.
[outlook_controller]

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"
require "mailman"

class OutlooksController < ApplicationController
    def index
        Mailman.config.poll_interval = 5  # change this number as per your needs. Default is 60 seconds
    Mailman.config.pop3 = {
  server: 'pop.outlook.com', port: 995, ssl: true,
  username: "user-name",
  password: "pass"
}
  Mailman::Application.run do
  default do
    begin
    p "Found a new message"
    p message.from.first # message.from is an array
    p message.to.first # message.to is an array again..
    p message.subject
    rescue Exception => e
      Mailman.logger.error "Exception occurred while receiving message:n#{message}"
      Mailman.logger.error [e, *e.backtrace].join("n")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The code here does not produce the same error on my box as you report here.  Instead of "Name or service not known," the error I get is "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."  What happens when you try this command from a command prompt?: `ping pop.outlook.com`

Comment: When I am trying to ping I am getting no response ...

Comment: You have a network problem, not a code problem.  `pop.outlook.com` is pingable for me.

Comment: I have tried from other places .I am able to ping but still I am getting error .do u know any other address other than pop.outlook.com